# How to find the nearest value in array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have the following array:

```
y_new = [0.0057602140000000005, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0057104540000000002, nan, 0.0056821390000000001, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0056911319999999998, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0054902060000000001, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0053461740000000004, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0055180319999999991, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0051784170000000003, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0051544399999999997, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.005136781, nan, nan, 0.0051989519999999997, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0051330490000000006, 0.0052893050000000002, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0053077380000000002, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0053766209999999998, 0.0053431900000000003, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0051352960000000001]
```

I want to select a random point in that array and work out where the nearest real value is above or below it. The non-real values are the "nan" and the real values are the numbers. I then want to calculate the difference in spacing between these two points where the difference between `y_new[5]` and `y_new[6]` is just 1 day.

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems really simple. So either I'm missing some key piece of information or you haven't tried. I'm hopefully assuming the former?

Comment: Where does this "1 day" come from? I don't see any dates here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python programmer but I think something like would give you what you want.

```
randomIndex = 5;
sizeofArray = 200;
lessThan = 0;
greaterThan = 0;

for(int i = randomIndex; i >=0; i---)
{
value = y_new[i];
if(value != nan)
{
lessThan = i;
return;
} 

}

for(int i = randomIndex; i <sizeOfArray; i++)
{
value = y_new[i];
if(value != nan)
{
greaterThan = i;
return;
} 

}

less = randomIndex - lessThan;
great = greaterThan - randomIndex;

if(less < great) return less;
else return great
```

Comment: for initially generating `randomIndex` and `sizeofArray` use `randomIndex = Random().nextInt(sizeofArray)` and `sizeofArray = len(y_new)`

Comment: Thank you, will give that a go! 

I'm completely new to coding so trying to learn.  @james

Comment: @CharlesHolroyd If you are this new and are still working with algorithms at this level, I would recommend learning to implement sorting algorithms. Insertion sort as a good starter, but then try to implement merge and selection sort WITHOUT looking at pseudocode for it, just the basic description of the algorithm. Also, since you're learning in python, play with the turtle module, as it gives you a way to visually see the paths your code is taking. Use it to learn how to take advantage of recursion and iteration to create insanely complex patterns with it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11247335)

Comment: @philippe This isn't a clarification, this is an answer.  Not a good answer, IMO, but still an answer.

Comment: Neither of the solutions given seem to give a correct answer. The following cannot give me the index value if the result is a "nan".

randomvalue = np.random.choice(y_new)
randomIndex = y_new.index(randomvalue)

Answer (score 0):

This is I think the most pythonic way to go...

Assuming index as your random index, 
y_new an array simplified,
the trick would be split your list (with slice)
and find the next real number in normal and reversed list.
Then sum the index for find th delta in days.
Hope it helps.

Here's a simple code:

```
index=4
y_new = [0.1, 'nan', 'nan', 0.2, 'nan','nan', 0.3,'nan']

nextList=y_new[index:]
beforeList=y_new[:index]

before_idx=(i for i,v in enumerate(list(reversed(beforeList))) if v!='nan').next()    
next_idx=(i for i,v in enumerate(nextList) if v!='nan').next()    

print y_new
print before_idx
print next_idx

print "interval between 2 real number near index %d is: %d days" %(index,(next_idx+before_idx+1))
```